# Unable to Access Spring Boot Actuator Endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I try to use actuator endpoints in spring boot. The application runs smoothly. My pom file is given below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleafdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>thymeleafdemo</name>
    <description>Ab Jove principium</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- umumi bağımlılıklar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the content of the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=DATABASE_URL
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

# Spring Data JPA properties
spring.data.jpa.repository.packages=com.yok.springboot.thymeleafdemo.dao
spring.data.jpa.entity.packages-to-scan=com.yok.springboot.thymeleafdemo.entity
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

#
# JDBC properties
#
app.datasource.jdbc-url=DATABASE_URL
app.datasource.username=USERNAME
app.datasource.password=PASSWORD

#
# Hikari properties
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=2000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000

# Actuator properties 
  
# expose all endpoints:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*  
management.endpoints.beans.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,env
management.endpoint.env.enabled=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true 
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
```

This is the start of my Spring Boot Application:

```java
package com.yok.springboot.thymeleafdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ThymeleafdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ThymeleafdemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to connect /health,/Info or /metrics endpoint by typing http://localhost:8080/health, the HTTP request transfers to http://localhost:8080/showMyLoginPage. I cannot reach endpoint. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit -1**
Mr. Fatih demands me to observe the result "http://localhost:8080/actuator" and this picture reveals: [the picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMFvDoYOKpzJXbHBJXL81GqmkVEQgxpH/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the console output of the application:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zYP1qe-Ohbcan93ZO6rqjxX9LqlGiIIg/view?usp=sharing

**Edit-2**  
The problem is partly solved. The actuators are available after the login of the application. But the problem is, after the login page, the homepage appears. All actuators are working, however, whenever I hit *http://localhost:8080/actuator/health* URL, {"status":"DOWN"} appears at the screen. Here is the console output taken during this operation:

reached urls: 

http://localhost:8080/showMyLoginPage
http://localhost:8080/students/list/page/1
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
http://localhost:8080/actuator/heapdump 
http://localhost:8080/actuator/env

console output: (exception has thrown)

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName
> or jdbcUrl is required.   at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1029)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109)
> ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]  at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]  at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]  at
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330)
> ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]  at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]   at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:105)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]   at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:100)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]

**Edit-3**

Mr Fatih pointed out some of the changes at the *WebSecurityConfiguration*. I have changed the code and I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with either
> HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests() or
> HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(). Please define one or the other
> but not both.

Here is the change I've made:

```java
/*
* import section have omitted for brevity
*/

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig {

    /*
     * other codes have omitted for brevity
     */

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                (authz) -> authz.antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.authorizeRequests(
                configurer -> configurer.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER"))

                .formLogin(configurer -> configurer.loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser").permitAll())

                .logout(configurer -> configurer.permitAll())

                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.accessDeniedPage("/access-denied"));

        return http.build();

    }

}
```

Here is the console output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CtjRBHXVRqirZ0Vt_3FEhx_N9oEwyfFZ/view

Comment: Actuator is available under `/actuator` and health for instance as `/actuator/health`. You are calling the wrong URLs.

Comment: The error you get states that you have an error in your configuration, fix that.

Comment: Please add your stacktraces as code not as quotes as those are poorly formatted and totally unreadable. I tried to edit it but that is a lost cause.

Comment: how to make it readable?

Comment: Copy/paste the stacktrace and add code formatting tags (triple backticks before and after it).

Comment: But as stated there is an error in your datasource configuration (you have multiple) Chagne the `jdbc-url` in your properties to just `url`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `spring-security` package for application security. So when you want to access your `/actuator` endpoints, you need to log in first. If you want to access your `/actuator` endpoints without logging in, you must configure a security configuration. With the following configuration, you can exclude all endpoints starting with `/actuator` from security.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Since `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated, you can do this as well.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(autz -> autz
                .mvcMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
    return http.build();
    }
}
```

`**` is a wildcard definition and allows you to access this endpoint without logging in, regardless of what comes after the actuator part.

Comment: Dear Fatih, I applied your proposal, but no way. The HTTP request lands to default controller action method.

Comment: Could you please add the return of your `http://localhost:8080/actuator` endpoint to your question?

Comment: Dear Fatih, I write the proposed URL to my browser and I added the result as a picture to the original post. Please look at the Edit-1.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer if you don't have a security configuration add a configuration file like this. If it is, add your `/actuator` endpoint to the existing one.

Comment: Dear Fatih, thank you for your efforts. As you know, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. FilterChain method is used instead of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. The problem here is simple. The status information has shown after the login, namely, after you enter your username and password, actuator is available.

Comment: Yes `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been removed. I've included a part of it in my answer that also shows how to do it using `SecurityFilterChain` instead.

Comment: Dear Fatih, thank you for your efforts. I have made the changes you've stated and I've got  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with either HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests() or HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(). Please define one or the other but not both.". Could you please check Edit-3?

Comment: Yes, I made a small cp error. I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Please Consider using a version for your dependency as far as i remember 1.9.5 RELEASE or 1.9.5 might help in this context , i had the same issue a year ago.

Comment: Suggesting to mix jars from different versions of a framework is a terrible idea and suggestion.

Comment: What are the possible consequences of mixing jars from different versions of a framework?

Comment: Weird class not found, abstractmethod errors, other incompatible libraries being used. All in all a joy to debug, generally solved by adding more more and unneeded dependencies, leading to troubles upgrading later on (due to now having fixed dependencies).